# Importing list of IP addresses into array/list Python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, csv

I am working on a small project to take a list of IPs/subnet and convert them into separate IP address and subnet mask. I am using netaddr to complete the change and am now working on importing a list of IPs like below into and array or list.

13.107.6.152/31

13.107.19.10/31

23.103.160.0/20

23.103.224.0/19 ...etc

I started in a txt file trying to import line by line, and have tried using a csv file with spaces delimited as well as putting commas and using that as the delimiter.

This is my my most recent work using this as the csv file

```
    13.107.6.152/31,13.107.19.10/31,23.103.160.0/20


with open('FileLocation.csv', 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
ipArray = list(reader)
```

However when I do:

```
print len(ipArray)
print ipArray
```

It only returns 1 and then a block of the IP addresses.

Is there a better way to format the IPs in the csv or text file that will help me insert them into the array or list? My goal is to get each individual IP in its own spot so I can run it through a loop.

Thanks :)

Comment: check the delimiter you've put in your reader, and those you have in your source file

Comment: A [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-contents) operates on rows - it returns a list for each row.  If you only have one row, you will get a list of the items; you should be able to iterate over that list.

Comment: CSV is a *tabular* format. If you can't explain what it means for an IP address to be in column 1, column 2, etc., then you might want to reformat your data.

Comment: Believe it or not, [there is a library for that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)... :-)

Answer (score 0):

With a txt file with 1 IP per line the following will accomplish what you need:

```
with open('IPs.txt', 'r') as fin:
    ips = fin.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: Or just iterate over the lines in the file and operate on them.